# How to assign current date to a date field in odoo 10

Tags: date, odoo, odoo-10

How to show current date before clicking the date field in odoo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it.It is Simple, just write this on your python code like:

```
date = fields.Datetime(string="Date", default=lambda *a: datetime.now(),required=True)
```

or

like this

```
date = fields.Datetime(string="Date current action", default=lambda *a: datetime.now())
```

or

like this

```
date = fields.Date(default=fields.Date.today)
```

Comment: Actually that is not the correct way of doing it. I will post an answer how to do it and why to do it that way.

Comment: Correctness has nothing to do with lines of code... Odoo is saving datetime as UTC in database. Your solution will produce some nice problems when using timezones for example in the USA and times around midnight.

Comment: Okay @CZoellner

Answer (score 5):

Odoo `Date` field class provides methods to get default values for like today.

For dates the method is called [context_today()](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/bc623461b3783da4767035f28e0f0ba59db82839/odoo/fields.py#L1491) and for datetimes [context_timestamp()](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/bc623461b3783da4767035f28e0f0ba59db82839/odoo/fields.py#L1554). You are able to pass a timestamp to this methods to either get today/now (without timestamp) or a timestamp which will be formed by the logged in users timezone.

Code Example:

```py
from odoo import fields, models


class MyModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.model'

    def _default_my_date(self):
        return fields.Date.context_today(self)

    my_date = fields.Date(string='My Date', default=_default_my_date)
```

Or the lambda version:

```py
    my_date = fields.Date(
        string='My Date', default=lambda s: fields.Date.context_today(s))
```